# How can I give tags of tag custom style?

Tags: visualforce, css, stylesheets

I've PageBlockSection tags inside PageBlock tag, and I want to give all PageBlockSection tags inside PageBlock tag with specific id a custom style. Any Idea ?

```
<apex:pageBlock id="BlockWithRedColor" >
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Block Section One" id="Section1">
              <apex:outputLabel >Hey</apex:outputLabel>
          </apex:pageblocksection>
          <apex:PageBlockSection title="Block Section Two" id="Section2">

          </apex:PageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock id="BlockWithBlueColor" >
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Block Section One" id="Section11">
              <apex:outputLabel >Hey</apex:outputLabel>
          </apex:pageblocksection>
          <apex:PageBlockSection title="Block Section Two" id="Section22">

          </apex:PageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one solution here is to wrap pageBlockSections with an outputPanels that got some css class assigned:

```
<style type="text/css">
.myClass1 label { 
    color: red; 
}

.myClass2 label{ 
    color: green; 
}
</style>

<apex:pageBlock id="BlockWithRedColor" tabStyle="Account">

    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="myClass1">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Block Section One">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Text 1" />
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="myClass1">
        <apex:PageBlockSection title="Block Section Two">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Text 2" />
        </apex:PageBlockSection>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="myClass2">
        <apex:PageBlockSection title="Block Section Three">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Text 3" />
        </apex:PageBlockSection>
    </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: It's work fine, thank you. but I thought I'll find something like normal style with html like. div input{ color:red; }

Comment: @user3003810 It is possible as well. I just wanted to show pure visualforce possibility :)

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the most efficient way you can try out like below

for your code above the actual ids generated looks like

*

> j_id0_BlockWithRedColor_Section1  & j_id0_BlockWithRedColor_Section2

*

the format is j_ido_pageblockid_pageblocksectionid

you can try applying styles to with these id as you do normally in CSS

Comment: I've above code inside a form , I tried your code but nothing happened ! maybe the error with my code not yours. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use CSS selectors like [id $= BlockWithRedColor] to directly style pageBlocks that have a given Id:

```
<style>
  div[id$=BlockWithRedColor] label {
    color: red;
  }
  div[id$=BlockWithBlueColor] label {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>

 <apex:pageBlock id="BlockWithRedColor" >
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Block Section One" id="Section1">
          <apex:outputLabel >Hey</apex:outputLabel>
      </apex:pageblocksection>
      <apex:PageBlockSection title="Block Section Two" id="Section2">

      </apex:PageBlockSection>

 </apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock id="BlockWithBlueColor" >
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Block Section One" id="Section11">
          <apex:outputLabel >Hey</apex:outputLabel>
      </apex:pageblocksection>
      <apex:PageBlockSection title="Block Section Two" id="Section22">

      </apex:PageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

[image]